# How to define context in a kotlin object

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I define a context for the progressdialog within such an object

```
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog

object Constants {
    //These are all the constants within our application
    const val permission_request = 100
    val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val progressDialog = SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(thecontext).build()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a `lateinit` context property that you set in your Application class. Then make the property that's dependent on it Lazy. But in this case, it doesn't make sense, because a Dialog is transient. It wouldn't be a constant. You can't reuse dialogs, because Android destroys and recreates the Activities/Fragments that host them according to various lifecycle processes.

But if you do have something like a constant that needs a Context, this is how you could do it:

```
object Constants {
    lateinit var context: Context
    val foo by lazy { Foo(context) }
}

class MyApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Constants.context = this
    }
}
```

And make sure you set `.MyApplication` as the Application name in the manifest.